# counter increment in awk if condition not working

Tags: awk

I want to count number of times the value "gafgyt" is coming in my input file.
My input file input.txt is :

```
"result": "Gen:Variant.New.Linux.Gafgyt.5"
"result": null
"result": "ELF:Gafgyt-DZ"
"result": null
"result": "Gen:Variant.Linux.Gafgyt.5"
```

and my code is :

`awk -F ":" 'BEGIN { i=1 } IGNORECASE = 1 { if ($2 ~ /gafgyt/) { i++;print $2} else {} }' input.txt`

But value of counter i is not getting incremented.

Comment: wrt `i is not getting incremented.` - I bet it is, what makes you think it isn't? ALso, awk is made up of `condition { action }` blocks - making `IGNORECASE = 1` a condition and having it evaluated/tested once per input line makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep` as well, if you don't care where the search string occurs in the input line.

```
$ grep -ic 'gafgyt' ip.txt 
3
```

Note that in your attempt, you used `:` as field separator and wanted to check only second field, but `"result": "ELF:Gafgyt-DZ"` will result in `Gafgyt-DZ"` in third field because there are two `:` before that.

Answer (score 4):

To simply count the number of string in whole Input_file try:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/gafgyt/{count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Above will consider 1 occurrence per line only, in case your lines can have multiple occurrences of string and you want to count them all then try following.

```
awk '{count+=gsub(/[gG][Aa][fF][gG][yY][tT]/,"&")} END{print count}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{lc=tolower($0); count+=gsub(/gafgyt/,"",lc)} END{print count} ' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked. What was the problem with my code?

Comment: @mishamehra, you were not printing value of `i` like in above code in END block also there is no need to else also here, with only if it should work.